# AWS SQS based trigger for Lambda drops messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue configured with a Dead Letter Queue. There are 2 Lambdas that are trigger by the SQS queue events. Each of them have a different [filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax) which enables them to process messages meant for them. The filters look like below:

```
{ "body" : { "ErpId" : [ "myErp1" ] } }
```

and

```
{ "body" : { "ErpId" : [ "someOtherErp" ] } }
```

When I send 6 messages to the SQS queue where 3 have ErpId *myErpId* and the other 3 have ErpId *someOtherErp*, it is observed that some or all of the messages for *myErpId* are dropped.

I can see all 6 of them come into SQS queue, 3 of them are picked up by Lambda for *someOtherErp* but the other Lambda only receives some of the messages. Those messages are not found in the SQS queue or in the Dead Letter Queue and neither can I see them in the CloudWatch Log Group for either Lambdas.

Any idea as to what is going on here?

Update:  both the Lambdas drop few messages (or the trigger drops them)

Comment: Have you read the section titled [Handling records that don't meet filter criteria](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-criteria-not-met)? It says, _For Amazon SQS, if a message doesn't satisfy your filter criteria, Lambda automatically removes the message from the queue. You don't have to manually delete these messages in Amazon SQS._ I suspect you'll need to accept all messages from the queue and then route them to different/specific queues based on the `ErpId` that they contain.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so basically the filters are of no use? In my case the at least one filter should match the criteria, so i expect the message to be processed by one of the lambdas.

Comment: I'm only guessing at the behavior, I've not actually tested it myself, but that's my reading of the docs such as they are.

Comment: I read the doc and did the PoC which resulted in the behavior mentioned in the question. Now I am in contact with AWS support who are investigating as to why the messages are not being picked up even though the filters are correct. Probably, they are meant to be dropped but I will update here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into that problem last year and [wrote a blog about it](https://www.tecracer.com/blog/2022/01/lambda-sqs-event-filters-may-delete-your-messages-if-youre-not-careful.html) (yes, yes - written by me and relevant).

If you have a queue with multiple subscribers, e.g. Lambda & EC2 where the Lambda has a filter, you may lose some or all of the messages that don't match the filter because Lambda discards the messages that don't.

[image: Diagram explaining the filter behavior]

A workaround would be an SNS topic with a queue per Lambda attached to it to duplicate the messages.

Comment: Thanks. I have resorted to a similar design now.